# Assigning a function in variable

Tags: ruby

In Javascript we can do this

```
var c = {

    firstname: "Bob",
    lastName: "Smith"
    log: function()
    {
        return "Hey" + this.firstname + " " + this.lastName;
    }

};
```

Can we do anything like this in ruby? I.E where does the usage of "This" come in, and also can we stack functions inside a variable? I'm new to ruby but the feature of "hashes" seems awfully similiar in a sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash items have no access to parent hash and hence hash’s nested siblings. What you are looking for is a class.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @first_name = "Bob"
    @last_name = "Smith"
  end

  def log
    "Hey #{@first_name} #{@last_name}"
  end
end

MyClass.new.log
#⇒ "Hey Bob Smith"
```

I believe it makes sense to read a book on Ruby syntax and/or basic concepts before trying to play with.

Answer (score -1):

In ruby there is the concept of [Proc and Lambda](http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/what-is-the-difference-between-a-block/), which is similar.

Example:

```
def create_lambda
  lambda { "You're looking at me?" }
end

some_var = create_lambda
some_var.call   #=> "You're looking at me?"
```

You can also pass parameters:

```
def create_square
  lambda { |base| base * base }
end

square = create_square
square.call(4) # => 16
```

Be aware, however, that lambdas, nor procs, take optional arguments, you always have to give them exactly the ones you defined.

In your example, the hash can not be referenced before it has been created.

So, for your example, you could do:

```
my_hash = {
  firstname: "Bob",
  lastName: "Smith"
}

my_hash['log'] = lambda { "Hey #{my_hash['firstname']} #{my_hash['lastName']}" }

my_hash['log'].call  #=> "Hey Bob Smith"
```

Comment: Note `this` usage in the given example. There is no “this” analogue in procs, they derive the outermost context. And, btw, `return`s are the code smell.

Answer (score -1):

you can try Struct

```
require 'ostruct'

Person = Struct.new(:firstname, :lastName) do
    def log
        "Hey" + self.firstname + " " + self.lastName
    end
end

person = Person.new('Bob', 'Smith')
puts person.log
```